# Map an array in functional component from API

Tags: arrays, react-native, fetch-api, picker

I want to call and display the API in the picker react native. I don't understand how to do it in the functional component, in the map section so that it gets the value

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Picker} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {

    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://aboutreact.herokuapp.com/demosearchables.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            console.log(responseJson.results)
            setSelectedValue(responseJson.results)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }, []);

    return (        
        <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={selectedValue.id}
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue) => setSelectedValue({ id: itemValue })}>
                    { ???.map((selectedValue, i) => {
                        return <Picker.Item key={i} value={selectedValue.id} label={selectedValue.name} />
                    })}
                </Picker>
               </View> 
        
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: `selectedValue` is an array or is and object? I ask because `const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState([]);` states it is an array, then this: `(itemValue) => setSelectedValue({ id: itemValue })`  states it is an object with an id key...

Comment: thank you for your attention and your question helps to my knowledge..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use an array to store your initial values for the `Picker`.
2. Then, setState on that array when the API is resolved.
3. Use another state to store the selected value.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Picker} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]);
    const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://aboutreact.herokuapp.com/demosearchables.php')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            setValues(responseJson.results)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }, []);

    return (        
        <View style={{flex: 1,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={selectedValue ? selectedValue.id : null}
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue) => setSelectedValue({ id: itemValue })}>
                    { values.map((value, i) => {
                        return <Picker.Item key={i} value={value.id} label={value.name} />
                    })}
                </Picker>
               </View> 
        
    )
}
```